# How to only allow 10 dynamic fields to be added javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have a dynamic form that add fields dynamically. I don't know where to create the rule for "maxdynamicfields: 10,"

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum++;
        var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value="' + frm.add_qty.value + '"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="' + frm.add_name.value + '"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></p>';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
        frm.add_qty.value = '';
        frm.add_name.value = '';
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an "if" statement to the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var rowNum = 0;
  function addRow(frm) {
    if (rowNum <10) {
      rowNum++; //only increase rowNum up to 10
      var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]"       size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
      jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
      frm.add_qty.value = '';
      frm.add_name.value = '';
    }
  }

  //Other functions
</script>
```

Comment: works well. now i will just disable the submit button if there are not 10 fields, else submit

Comment: Where would i disable the submit and only enable submit after 10 fields are active. 

$('#submit1').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
    else {
        $('#submit1').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: This is not the most elegant solution, but this should work. You can add another if statement to the same function. Add the following statement after .append(row) line:

    if (rowNum ===10) {
      $("#submit1").prop("disabled", true);
    }

Answer (score 2):

Although you already are having a count `rowNum`, you could just use that in your function to check the count. Alternatively you could use something like this :

```
var count = $('p[id^=rowNum]').length;
    if(count >= 10) {
    // meaning there are atleast 10 dynamic elements created
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid polluting global namespace with `rowNum` variable, and use this condition:

```
$('#itemRows > p > input').length >= 10
```

or a simple way:

```
rowNum >= 10
```

Secondly, your answer - the best place would be inside addRow function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowNum = 0;
    function canAddRow(){
        return $('#itemRows input').length >= 10 / /max row count is 10 here.
    }

    function addRow(frm) {
        if(canAddRow()) 
            return;
        rowNum ++;
        var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]"       size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
        frm.add_qty.value = '';
        frm.add_name.value = '';
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since there is no `rowNum--` in the `removeRow()`, it cannot be used as a condition check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowNumber variable for this purpose

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
    if(rowNumber == 10) 
      return;
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]"       size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a maximum value and test for it, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var rowNum = 1;
  var MAX = 10;

  function addRow( frm ) {

    if (rowNum > MAX ) {
         resetQtyName( frm );
         return;
    }
    else
    {
      var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]"       size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
      jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);

      // prepare for next invocation
      resetQtyName( frm );
      rowNum++; 
    }
  }

function removeRow(rnum) {
    rowNum -= 1;
    jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
}
function resetQtyName( frm ){
      frm.add_qty.value = '';
      frm.add_name.value = '';

}
</script>
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you wish to use semantic HTML,as well as more of a jQuery solution, see http://jsfiddle.net/dvw30tjv/16